# QuantLib 1.8.1 build error

Tags: boost, quantlib

I cannot directly download boost library nor quantlib from sourceforge.net/ due to web control inside company. So I downloaded QuantLib v1.8.1 from github, added linking to boost library v1.60 (I also tried v1.61) which is available in the share folder (I tested, boost library works fine), and tried to build under VS2015 x64-release.

The error message I got was (after processing to errors.cpp):

C2757  'boost': a symbol with this name already exists and therefore this name cannot be used as a namespace name.

I'm wondering if it's due to a setup error? How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "downloaded from GitHub" do you mean a git clone, or a zip download? Also, how exactly did you add the Boost libraries?

Comment: Add a screenshot or logs please.